# How do I trap enter from form except textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

In a dynamic form, I have the following code to trap 'enter' key.

```
$(document).bind('keypress', function (e) {  
  if (e.keyCode == 13) { 
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Occasionally, there is an element like HTMLTextAreaElement which accept 'enter' key.

how do I unbind preventDefault only for HTMLTextAreaElement.

TIA.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What default behavior are you not trying to prevent with a textarea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (e.which == 13 && e.target.localName !== 'textarea') {
```

Comment: What's the difference between `localName` & `tagName`?

Comment: @JosephSilber localName is mainly used for XML document's elements, I just used it as it returns a lowercase string.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("html *:not(textarea)").bind('keypress', function (e) {  
  if (e.keyCode == 13) { 
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/4JWLb/

Comment: You are so confident with your fiddle? Some how it is not Not working!

Comment: @Gian - Hmm, this is strange. [`$("html *:not(textarea)")`](http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/LshyK/) returns all elements except `textarea`, but it is also applying to the `textarea` too. Looks like a bug.